# Sort alphanumeric list

Tags: list, sorting

I'm trying to sort this list by the numbers found in each element.

```
revision_type = [('100K Revision', '50K Revision', '25K Revision')]
```

This is what I've come up with so far but keep getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'partition'
revision_sorted = sorted(revision_type, key=lambda s: (int(s.partition(' ')[0][:-1])))
```

I want the list `revision_sorted` to be:

```
[('25K Revision', '50K Revision', '100K Revision')]
```

Been messing with this for hours, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what language are oyu using?

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were very close. revision_type is a list which has a tuple. So, you have to extract the first element and pass to the sorted function.

```
revision_type = [('100K Revision', '50K Revision', '25K Revision')]
revision_sorted = [tuple(sorted(revision_type[0], key=lambda s: (int(s.partition(' ')[0][:-1]))))]
print revision_sorted
```

**Output**

```
[('25K Revision', '50K Revision', '100K Revision')]
```